# ESP8266-01 no serial output

Tags: arduino, serial-port, esp8266

I'm new to arduino and stuff like that. I have an arduino nano and an `esp8266-01` (https://www.reichelt.de/entwicklerboards-esp8266-wifi-modul-debo-esp8266-p192142.html). I have the `Vcc` connected to `3V3` and the ESP `GND` to the `GND` of the arduino. `GPO0` is grounded and `RX` of the ESP is connected to the `RX` of the arduino (`Tx` to `Tx` too). I know, that i should use resistors between the `RX` connections, but when i do that, the esp times out (i guess my usb cable is too long...). I use the version 2.7.4 of the `ESP8266` and i can upload without an error.
I am using this example code:

```
/*
    This sketch demonstrates how to scan WiFi networks.
    The API is almost the same as with the WiFi Shield library,
    the most obvious difference being the different file you need to include:
*/
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set WiFi to station mode and disconnect from an AP if it was previously connected
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Setup done");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("scan start");

  // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n == 0) {
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  } else {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      Serial.print(i + 1);
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
      Serial.print(")");
      Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == ENC_TYPE_NONE) ? " " : "*");
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait a bit before scanning again
  delay(5000);
}
```

My problem is, that i get no serial outputs. I read on forums, that i have to use software serials, but it didn't do a thing.
In tutorials (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJnpgYlelEA) they just connect the ESP and it works without any problems. Can someone please explain this to me?
Thanks!

Comment: with io 0 to ground the esp8266 starts in flashing mode

Comment: yeah but without that i cant upload. What should i do instead?

Comment: put a button on io 0